# $scope.variable is undefined in browser console while form submit AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want `$scope.variable` value in browser console but its always occur undefined.

form.htm

```
<form>
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" 
required /></p>

<button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>
</form>
```

myctr.js

```
app.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'ngCart', '$localStorage',
 '$sessionStorage', '$window',
 function($scope, $http, ngCart, $localStorage,
     $sessionStorage, $window) {
     $scope.SendData = function() {
         console.log($scope.firstName)
         $window.alert($scope.firstName)
     };
 }
]);
```

Comment: paste full html code

Comment: $scope variable is defined in the controller section only, your browser console i not inside of your controller, so $scope is undefined in your browser console

Comment: site is too big, i just create a separate page and trying to getting problem solve. :(

Comment: Maybe you forgot the `ng-controller` tag

Comment: i am not getting you point, would you like to share code?

Comment: ng-controller is given

Comment: Give the form a name (i.e., vm.myForm) then reference it via that form in the controller (this.myForm.firstName)

Comment: It is a good practice to initialise the variables shared between view & controller. Try initialising variable like so : $scope.variable = ''; inside your controller

Comment: i tried this method, in console its appearing object

Comment: i really need to solve this issue

Comment: Are you injecting the controller in your html?

Comment: is alert($scope.firstName) working? at least a black popup? try changing the variable name once.

Comment: in alert, appearing undefined

Comment: yes injecting controller

Comment: Does your form submit when you click the button? I.e. does the page refresh? If you don't actually want to submit the form, you should change the button type to `button`. Like so: `<button type="button">`. Whether it'll fix this issue, I cannot say.

Comment: did you try changing the variable name?? try once with some unique name!!! and please test once removing all the dependencies with only injecting $scope. and let me know if it works. I see there is no problem with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Possible problem is that you're using a simple string value `$scope.firstName`. If your input is more than one scope "deeper" in the DOM hierarchy, then your `$scope.firstName` and `ng-model` in the input become two independent variables so no wonder that you get `$scope.firstName` undefined. That's the typical problem with simple types and scopes inheritance. Possible ways to solve this would be:

- use object to bind data between the controller and template: `$ctrl.user.firstName` and `<input ng-model="user.firstName"`>.
- use the "controllerAs" syntax.

Read more on this in documentation on [controllers](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/api/ng/directive/ngController) and [scopes](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/docs/guide/scope).

Comment: not working with $scope', '$http', 'ngCart','$localStorage', '$sessionStorage','$window'

Answer (score 0):

use the following modified code ---

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngStorage']);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $window,$http,$localStorage,$sessionStorage) {
    $scope.SendData = function() {
    console.log($scope.firstName)
    $window.alert($scope.firstName)
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/ngstorage/0.3.6/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<form>
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName" 
required /></p>

<button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>
</form> 
</div>
```

Modified the answer...

Comment: i have tried all this methods, its will work, but its not working with this  '$scope', '$http', 'ngCart','$localStorage', 
'$sessionStorage','$window'

Comment: thanks for efforts, can you solve this issue with this  $scope', '$http', 'ngCart','$localStorage', '$sessionStorage','$window' ?

Comment: modified the answer a bit...not aware of ngCart .. but have to add to app dependencies

Answer (score 0):

As per the definition of **ngModel** it will try to bind to the property given by evaluating the expression on the current scope. If the property doesn't already exist on this scope, it will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

Here when submit is clicked without filling the text box $scope.firstName is undefined because firstName it is not defined in the current $scope.

If something is typed in the text box , as per the definition of ng-model a firstName property will be created implicitly and added to the scope.

Let controller be

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.lastName=''; 

  $scope.SendData = function() {
    console.log($scope.firstName)
    alert($scope.firstName)
    };

    $scope.CheckLast = function() {
    console.log($scope.lastName)
    alert($scope.lastName)
    };

});
```

HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form>
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" ng-model="firstName"/></p>
<button ng-click="SendData()">Submit</button>
<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" ng-model="lastName"/></p>
<button ng-click="CheckLast()">Submit</button>
</form>
</body>
```

Here [Demo plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/LkreCkEl9UDblldYswx8?p=preview) you can see firstName is undefined while lastName is not as last name is initialised within the scope. and if something will be filled to firstName text box before submit the it is defined.